# Optimization problem with quadratic form of an arbitrary matrix

Tags: matrices

I want to optimize the following optimization problem, where $A$ is an arbitrary matrix not a Hermitian matrix, most of literature I've surveyed put constraint on $A$, is there an efficient algorithm to solve it?

$$\min_x \lvert x^H A x\rvert^2
\quad\text{s.t.}\quad\lVert x\rVert^2 = 1.$$

Comment: Your quantity is the point in the numerical range of $A$ with minimum modulus. Since you can efficiently compute/draw the boundary of the numerical range (see the Horn and Johnson book, for example), you can efficiently compute your quantity.

Comment: I have seen the Horn and Johnson book, however most cases dicessed in the book are restricted to A as a symmetric or Hermitian matrix, can you give me an example? Thank you very much!

Comment: If $A$ was symmetric or Hermitian, the numerical range would just be a straight line segment along the real line. Look up "numerical range" in Horn and Johnson -- for non-Hermitian $A$ it is a convex subset of the complex plane. The book describes how to compute its boundary.